# Converting a yaml sequence to a yaml map in a helm chart (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm values file (yaml) containing the following block:

```
env:
- name: <key>
  value: <value>
- name: <key1>
  value: <value1>
```

I would like to inject the above block into a kubernetes configmap definition. The result should look the following:

```
data: 
  key: value
  key1: value1
```

I tried the following, however the resulting file would contain a yaml sequence instead of a yaml map:

```
{{ toYaml .Values.env }}
```

Any advise helping me to solve the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
{{- range .Values.env }}
  {{ .name }}:{{ .value}}
{{- end }}
```